# Sublime Text 2 packages won't install

Tags: package, sublimetext2

I installed package control in Sublime Text 2, that worked fine.

I tried installing Xdebug first. The bar at the bottom was indicating that it was "installing" Xdebug. It went on for a long time and then stopped. When I checked, nothing had been downloaded or installed.

I manually placed the Xdebug package and it showed up on the list.

But I can't actually install any package via the package control.

I'm running this on Debian 7, in my home directory without sudo. Still, it's my home folder so rights shouldn't be a problem.

I tried running as root but that just doesn't seem like a good solution to me.

So, nothing gets downloaded and installed and there are no error messages. Can anybody help me determine the cause of this and how to fix it?

EDIT: opened the console, tried installing SublimeLinter, and I'm being told an HTTP 502 error occurred, which is a "bad gateway" error. I googled this and most I get are technical explanations and the fact that "a piece of equipment might be failing". Not very helpful.

Comment: open up the Sublime console with ctrl-` and see what it says there

Comment: @MattDMo Turns out it's due to an HTTP 502 error. I edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Github is currently experiencing a service outage (https://status.github.com/) which prevents the Sublime Text Package Control from downloading packages from Github.

Comment: Aha. Well, I should have checked that first instead of assuming it would be a lot more complicated. Thanks for the help.

Comment: No worries! Github should be back to normal as of now by the way.